# Problema com a identificação de elementos

Tags: javascript

Estrutura do programa:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section onclick = 'clicar()'>
        <div id = 'a1'></div>
        <div id = 'a2'></div>
        <div id = 'a3'></div>
    </section>

<script>
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2').innerHTML
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3').innerHTML

    function clicar(){
           //DÚVIDA
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como eu identificaria dentro da function 'clicar()'quais as divs o usuario estaria clicando? ('a1', 'a2', 'a3').

Exemplo:

```
if (click == 'a1'){
     window.alert('Carro comprado')

}else if (click == 'a2'{
     window.alert('Carro vendido')

}else if (click == 'a3'){
      window.alert('Carro reembolsado')
}
```

Espero que esteja claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem três variáveis que são disponibilizadas para você utilizar nesses eventos declarados no HTML, o `this`, o `arguments`, e o `event`.

`event` contém o objeto representando a ação do evento, no caso, do clique. Essa objeto possue diversas propriedades e métodos com informações sobre o evento ocorrido, como qual elemento disparou o evento. Essa propriedade é a chamada `target`.

Como você pode ver no exemplo abaixo, basta utilizar a propriedade `target` do `event` para recuperar o elemento que disparou o evento:

```js
function clicar(event) {
    var target = event.target
    console.log('clicou na div ' + target.id)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section onclick = 'clicar(event)'>
        <div id = 'a1'>Div 1</div>
        <div id = 'a2'>Div 2</div>
        <div id = 'a3'>Div 3</div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém também pode ocorrer o cenário em que você possue elementos aninhados dentro dessa `div`, e se você clicar nesse elemento interno, não seria a `div` o elemento `target` do evento, `target` é o elemento que dispara o evento, nesse caso, você teria que usar uma query para procurar a `div` mais próxima do elemento clicado:

```js
function clicar(event) {
    var target = event.target
    var div = target.closest('.div-com-evento')
    console.log('clicou na div ' + div.id)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section onclick = 'clicar(event)'>
        <div id = 'a1' class = 'div-com-evento'><span>Div 1</span></div>
        <div id = 'a2' class = 'div-com-evento'><span>Div 2</span></div>
        <div id = 'a3' class = 'div-com-evento'><span>Div 3</span></div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você tem algum vídeo aula para me recomendar que se aprofunda mais nesse assunto? (this, arguments e events)

Comment: Vídeo aula? Não tenho não, conheço a documentação do MDN e W3schools.

Comment: Mas como eu faria para selecionar aquela div depois? Ex: `if (a1 ==  'X')`   eu tentei fazer `target.a1`  ou  `target.innerHTML.a1`  mas da undefined e não o valor que eu coloquei antes ('X').